How to change the same bone contraint value for multiple bones simultaneously?
I have many bones with Damped Track constraint. Is there a way to simultaneously change the influence value for all of them?


you can use a script for that:
import bpy

new_influence = 0.5

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'ARMATURE':
        for bone in obj.pose.bones:
            for constraint in bone.constraints:
               if constraint.type == 'DAMPED_TRACK':
                    constraint.influence = new_influence

bpy.context.view_layer.update()


Amazing, thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed! I will be able to accept your answer after 3 minutes!

I have no example to test it right now, but can you not simply select all bones and then Alt+click into the value field to change the value for all selected? Like you can in almost all other fields too?

Select all the bones and AltLMB on the value, type your value and Enter.

Thank you, this option works great too! I accept the previous option because it came earlier and because it does not require manually selecting all the necessary bones, but I will keep your option in mind, it is also very convenient, thank you very much!
